# Error while sending whatsapp message using pywhatkit

Tags: python, whatsapp

My Program should send whatsapp message using [pywhatkit](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit) library by taking input from user by speech recognition.

This is the function that send message.

```
def WhatsApp():
    speak("For Whom should i send message")
    Contacts = {
        'mom' : 63XXXXXXX,   # these are numbers (hidden)
        'karthik' : 75XXXXXXx,
        'me' : 81XXXXXXX,
        'jayaram' : 99XXXXXXXX
    }
    to = takeCommand() #takes my voice input using speech_recognition
    speak("what message should i send")
    msg = takeCommand()
    speak(f"sending message to {to}")
    try:
        pwt.sendwhatmsg_instantly(f"+91{Contacts[to]}",msg,5,True,15)
    except Exception as e:
        speak(f"error sending message")
        print(e)
```

When i say send whatsapp message to my Voice assistant it will ask me for whom to send and what msg it should send.

I used pywhatkit send whatsapp msg instantly function so that msg could send fastly but its just opening whatsapp web and returning back.

My Problem :

- Whatsapp web is opening and goes to contact number and my message will be there ready to be sent but it wont send my msg and closes the tab after some time.

Note:

- i also tried to change the close tab time in function parameter of pwt.sendWhatmsg_instantly(a,b,c,d,closetab time) but no use the result was same.

Please help me find a better way to do this sending message instantly through pywhatkit and to solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `pyautoguit` module. Add `pyautogui.press(“enter”)` after
`pwt.sendwhatmsg_instantly(f"+91{Contacts[to]}",msg,5,True,15)`

Also, there is can be issues if you use multiple displays.